# Rails dynamic where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I have a where clause being called based off of a json object from a form. The object has a series of boolean values for locales which will be used to find Venues within the given locale.

Is there a better way to write a series of queries than having a long string built off of boolean values? Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

*hard_worker.rb*

```
def build_locales
  filters = []
  filters.push 'locale_north' if @lead.locale_north
  filters.push 'locale_south' if @lead.locale_south
  filters.push 'locale_east' if @lead.locale_east
  filters.push 'locale_west' if @lead.locale_west

  return filters
end

def build_string
  filters = build_locales
  s = ''
  filters.each_with_index do |f, i|
    s+= "#{f} = true"
    s+= " OR " if i < filters.size - 1
  end
end

def perform(lead_id)
  @venues = Venue.where(receive_all: true).or(Venue.where(build_string))
  // ... more code ...
end
```

Comment: Will those dynamic conditions form the intersection(joining them with `AND`) or it will be joining with OR condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`where` clauses are chainable so you can easily do a lot of querying if you need to with an approach like this.

```rb
@venues = Venue.all
@venues = @venues.where(receive_all: true)
filters.each do |filter|
  @venues = @venues.or(Venue.where(filter.to_sym: true))
end
# after all of this you can just return @venues
@venues
```